# Need some ideas for a card replacement algorithm

Tags: algorithm

The problem is as following:

Two players have cards of the following format:
1.First player has cards with a letter on top [A-Z] and 1 or 2 letters on bottom
2.Second player has cards with a letter on top [A-Z] and a number on the bottom

When a card is played the letter from the top of the card is replaced with what is on the bottom.

Given a sequence of numbers and a initial played card the two players have to replace letters until the letter from the first played card transform into the given sequence.
The two players can use as many cards of each and there is no restriction on the order of who plays the cards.

Example:

```
Player one has cards: (A, BC), (B, F), (F, BF), (C, D)
Player two has cards: (F, 0), (D, 3), (B, 2), (B, 1), (R, 3)

The given sequence: (3, 2, 0)
The initial card played: (A, BC)

1.(A, BC) played: BC
2.(C, D) played: BD
3.(D, 3) played: B (3)
4.(B, F) played: F (3)
5.(F, BF) played: BF (3)
6.(B, 2) played: F (3, 2)
7.(F, 0) played: (3, 2, 0)
```

I tought about a backtracking aproach but I've been told that there is no need for such a method and I can't figure the proper method out

Comment: What is the maximum number of cards that each player can have? Is player1 forced to play `(A,BC)` first, or can player1 play any card to start?

Comment: the first card played is provided by the input, each player can have maximum 25 cards and can be used as many times as needed (the cards are also input for the problem)

Comment: What you are given is a context-free grammar in Chomsky normal form. Take a look at the Cocke-Younger-Kasami algorithm, it does exactly what you need. It is googleable by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, several observations:

> The two players can use as many cards of each and there is no restriction on the order of who plays the cards.

So that means that it actually doesn't matter that we have two players - what matters it which cards exist in the game.

Also, if cards have unlimited uses, using the letter->number and letter->letter cards, we can create an inverse map of numbers to a list of letters that lead to that number.

After these steps, if `<number of letters played>=<number of required numbers>`, it looks like an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

Otherwise (if `<number of letters played> < <number of required numbers>`) I think that it's solvable by a more complex [flow network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem).